# To make first letter in a string as capital and make the font as italic

Tags: html, css, jsp

How to make the first letter as capital in a string and display the string as italic..

```
Input:
hyptis suavalovens
I am trying to get the output like this...
*Hyptis suavalovens*
```

Comment: You want to do this in… Java?

Comment: it would be better if you could post some code. everyone is guessing here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it with CSS:

```css
p:first-letter {
    text-transform: capitalize;
}

p {
    font-style: italic;
}
```

```html
<p>input:hyptis suavalovens</p>
<p>i am trying to get the output like this...</p>
<p>*hyptis suavalovens*</p>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ez3Lv/2/

Comment: He wants only first letter of first work to be capital not first letter of every work.

Comment: Sir, I want to display like this Hyptis suavalovens, but it displays like this Hyptis Suavalovans.. I want to display the first letter as capital how to do this....

Comment: @VarunKrishnan can't you modify your HTML part?

Answer (score 2):

You can use :first-letter selector.

```
<p id="mytext">hyptis suavalovens</p>
#mytext{
    font-style: italic;
}
#mytext:first-letter {
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/77mmu/)

Answer (score 1):

use this

```
Input:first-letter {
text-transform: uppercase;
font-style: Italic;
}
```